# how to calculate quantity using BigQuery in GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to calculate number of transaction, quantity, revenue for last 14 days.
What I've got so far is

```
SELECT 
sum(totals.transactions) AS Transaction , 
sum(hits.product.productQuantity) AS quantity,
sum(totals.transactionRevenue)/1000000 AS Revenue
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_],
TIMESTAMP('2019-10-01'), TIMESTAMP('2019-10-14'));
```

I get transaction and revenue same as what I've got from custom report but some how I get different number for quantity.
Am I doing something wrong or using wrong table?

I suppose to get 63 for the quantity but I get 2420 when I run the big query above.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The query in the question produces no results. Thanks for choosing a public dataset source (so I could run the query), but there are no tables within that time range.

The same query over an existing time period:

```
SELECT 
sum(totals.transactions) AS Transaction , 
sum(hits.product.productQuantity) AS quantity,
sum(totals.transactionRevenue)/1000000 AS Revenue
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_],
TIMESTAMP('2017-07-01'), TIMESTAMP('2017-07-12'));

317     27804   33020.66
```

Then I rewrote it as a #standardSQL query - to see if there is some implicit flattening that creates incorrect results. In #standardSQL you have to do explicit flattening, which I did like this:

```
SELECT Transaction
  , (SELECT SUM((SELECT SUM(productQuantity) FROM UNNEST(product))) FROM UNNEST(hitsarray)) AS quantity
  , Revenue
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(totals.transactions) AS Transaction 
    , SUM(totals.transactionRevenue)/1000000 AS Revenue
    , ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(hits) hitsarray
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`
  WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN '20170701' AND '20170712'
)

317     27804   33020.66
```

And you can see that it gives me the same results. Is the `ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG()` + `SUM((SELECT SUM())` the correct way to unnest the hits and product data within? Well, depends on why you were expecting a different value. Please make that clear in the question.

Comment: I forgot to add hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '6' for the condition.That's why I got different answers with custom reports.